# React Navigation + Redux: How to pass props into StackNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to set up my StackNavigator with redux.

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { StackNavigator } from "react-navigation";

import ChatList from "../chat/chat-list";
import ChatDetail from "../chat/chat-detail";

// how do we pass props into this??
const ChatContainer = StackNavigator({
  ChatList: {
    screen: ChatList
  },
  ChatDetail: {
    screen: ChatDetail,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: "Jesus",
      tabBarVisible: false
    })
  }
});

export default connect(state => ({
  cool: state.cool,
}), dispatch => ({}))(ChatContainer);
```

how would I pass `cool` into StackNavigator and down to ChatList?

Comment: Have you discovered how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use Navigator Props

```
const SomeStack = StackNavigator({
  // config
});

<SomeStack
  screenProps={/* this prop will get passed to the screen components as this.props.screenProps */}
/>
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#Navigator-Props

new link for react-navigation 3.x

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#navigator-props

Comment: @SiweiShen申思维 I have provide new link for react navigation version 3.x it's been a long time since my answer so probably the api also changing

Comment: Yep, i just used screenProps to wire up all my navigators to redux.  Works really well, i just posted my solution on this medium article

https://medium.com/@michaelceber/wrapping-react-navigation-navigators-in-redux-containers-497b432b8911